# MongoDB UpdateMany Child Array without filter

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/yjbKtHQHAr-)

Simple Schema:

```
[
  {
    "key": 1,
    "Array": [
      {
        "Prop1": 1,
        "Prop2": 2
      },
      {
        "Prop1": 2,
        "Prop2": 3
      },
      
    ]
  },
]
```

I want to update all child array, but mongo says 'The positional operator did not find the match needed from the query.'

```
db.collection.update({},
{
  "$set": {
    "Array.$.Prop1": ""
  }
},
{
  "multi": true,
  "upsert": false
})
```

Comment: https://mongoplayground.net/p/na-f-4fbesd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
 db.collection.update({},
 {
   "$set": {
     "Array.$[].Prop1": ""
    }
  },
  {
    "multi": true,
    "upsert": false
  })
```

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ylzhdkY-9UB)